# Remove Bottom Borders from DataGrid in Material UI (mui)

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to override the default bottom border between each row in a MUI Data Grid Component, but have had no luck. So far, I've tried using a theme override, adding a `className` with `border` proeprty set to `none`, tried using the `sx` feature, and a custom `index.css` stylesheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my component:
`component.tsx`

```
   <div className = {classes.ListTable}>
       <DataGrid
           sx={{
               border: 0, // also tried setting to none 
               borderRadius: 2,
               p: 2,
               minWidth: 300,
           }}
           rows={rows}
           columns={columns}
           pageSize={5}
           rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
           checkboxSelection
           disableSelectionOnClick
           classes={{ root: classes.MuiTableCell}}
       />
    </div>
```

Here are the unsuccessful styling attempts I've had so far:

`theme.tsx`

```
const theme = createTheme({
  ...
   overrides: {
       DataGrid: {
           root:{
               border: 'none',
           }
       }
   }
});
```

`index.css`

```
.MuiPaper-root-MuiDrawer-paper, 
.MuiDataGrid-footerContainer, 
.MuiDataGrid-root, 
.MuiDataGrid-row, 
.MuiDataGrid-column, 
.MuiDataGrid {
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

`styles.tsx`

```
  ListTable: {
      borderBottom: "none",
      border: 0,
  },
   MuiTableCell: {
      borderBottom: "none",
      outline: 0,
      borderColor: "10px solid red",
      color: theme.palette.text.primary,
   }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated - thank you in advance.

Comment: In my `index.css` file, I added `* { border: none !important; }`, which works, but removes borders from everything. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also struggling with this. This is the solution I came up with. Its a little messy but it works. You can add this to your `styles.tsx`.

```
grid: {
'&>.MuiDataGrid-main': {
  '&>.MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders': {
    borderBottom: 'none',
  },

  '& div div div div >.MuiDataGrid-cell': {
    borderBottom: 'none',
  },
}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently found a slightly shorter way to remove all borders from a MUI's datagrid table, without removing the border of other components.

```
<DataGrid
  columns={columns}
  rows={rows}
  sx={{ '&, [class^=MuiDataGrid]': { border: 'none' } }}
  />
```

- `&` will target the DataGrid itself, removing the outer border of the table,
- `[class^=MuiDataGrid]'` uses an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#:%7E:text=language%20subcode%20matches.-,%5Battr%5E%3Dvalue%5D,-Represents%20elements%20with) to target every grid's child element with a `class` attribute that starts with `MuiDataGrid`

Answer (score 3):

In MUI v5 project I used this, and it's worked. Main borders are removed.

```
export const customTheme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiDataGrid: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    border: 'none'
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In MUI v5 , can be done by customizing the datagrid

```
  const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGrid)(({ theme }) => ({
    border: 0,
    color: '#757575',
    fontFamily: 'Lato',
    WebkitFontSmoothing: 'auto',
    letterSpacing: 'normal',
  '& .MuiDataGrid-row': {
   width: '1191px',
   height: '34px',
  background: '#FFFFFF',
  borderRadius: '27px',

},
'& .MuiDataGrid-iconSeparator': {
  display: 'none',
},
'& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders': {

  width: '1191px',
  minHeight: '34px',
  background: '#D5DFED',
  borderRadius: '20px',

},
'& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle': {
  fontWeight: 700,
  fontSize: '14px', minHeight: '34px',
},
'& .MuiDataGrid-row.Mui-selected': {
  background:' #FFFFFF',
  border: '1px solid #73A0FF',
  borderRadius:' 27px',
},
'& .MuiDataGrid-cell': {
  fontFamily:'Lato',
  fontWeight: 400,
  fontSize: '14px',
  lineHeight: '17px',
  color: '#757575',
  boxSizing: 'none',borderBottom: 'none',
},
'& .MuiPaginationItem-root': {
  borderRadius: 0,
}
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who is still facing the issue, here is a simple working solution with MUI v5 & v6:

```
<DataGrid 
sx={{ 
'&>.MuiDataGrid-main': {
                            '&>.MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders': {
                                borderBottom: 'none'
                            },

                            '& div div div div >.MuiDataGrid-cell': {
                                borderBottom: 'none'
                            }
                        }
}}

</>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried plopping a static css file in my project *and* a `class="peaches"` on a surrounding `<div>` so I can keep my styles logical without `!important`s.

This worked - it did remove all the borders I wanted to remove (between each row and also around the headers, footers, and table itself):

```css
.peaches .MuiDataGrid-root {
  border: 0;
}
.peaches .MuiDataGrid-cell {
  border: 0;
}
.peaches .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders {
  border: 0;
}
.peaches .MuiDataGrid-footerContainer {
  border: 0;
}
```

You don't need `!important` if you use CSS selector specificity for its intended purpose. The Chrome DevTools Styles inspector shows where the borders come from, and you can eyeball the selector count that MUI uses, and just ensure you beat them by numbers in your CSS.